# Using "rarely" to point out a disadvantageous aspect sounds like a praise

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, alternatives

Say I am reviewing a software (or whatever), and after talking about its good features I get to list its drawbacks:

> - Quite RAM consuming.
> - **Rarely** crashes when various keys are pressed at the same time.

The word *rarely* sounds out of place, as if it were good that a bad thing, namely crashing, rarely happens. The point is that it should never happen.

Is my impression genuine? If yes, what is a proper replacement for *rarely*? *Seldom*
and *unfrequently* seem to fail likewise. It must, of course, keep the meaning of something
that happens at a very low frequency.

Comment: Your impression is correct.  *Rarely* means something like "almost never".  But you don't want to say it "almost never crashes!", you want to say it sometimes *does* crash when you do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rarely* (like *rare*, *few*, *little*, *hardly*, and *seldom*) is a [negative polarity term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), so the implication is that it crashes less often than one might expect.

*Occasionally* (and *some*, *sometimes*, *a few*, *a little*) are not negative polarity terms, and do not have that implication.

So  you're right: it is out of place in your review, unless you're comparing it with a version, or a program, that crashes rather more. I think *occasionally* will serve your purpose.

Comment: Looks pretty good. It only seems to me that *occasionally* is more frequent than *rarely*, but then I think I can use "occasionally (but rarely)" to emphasize, does it look good?

Comment: To me, _occasionally_ is no more frequent than _rarely_ - it just lacks the negative polarity. But your emendation is OK.

Comment: Looking at [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=occasionally+but+rarely%2Crarely+but+occasionally&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coccasionally%20but%20rarely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crarely%20but%20occasionally%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Coccasionally%20but%20rarely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crarely%20but%20occasionally%3B%2Cc0) comparing ***occasionally but rarely*** with ***rarely but occasionally***, it's tempting to think that a century or two ago most people *did* think that "occasionally is more frequent than rarely". But not so much now.

Comment: Okay, you've got me, I'm old as hell :)